# Does MultiFormatReader in the zxing library decode in its own thread?

Tags: java, android, zxing

I am passing YUV data to the MultiFormatReader for decoding. I wanted to know if the library handles the decode process in its own thread.

Additionally, what is the ideal preview size to pass to the reader for quickest results?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not spawn any new threads anywhere in the library. Everything is done in the calling thread, serially.

I had once though of adding this as an option. You could still preserve the current priority order while doing some speculative decoding in parallel. Might end up wasting some work but get an answer in less wall-clock time. I didn't know if this was so useful, because usually, people know what one or few formats they're looking for anyway, and where multiple formats are of interest, it's usually 1D formats which are very fast anyway.

(In the Android app, that's not true; it's necessarily handled asynchronously with a `Handler`.)

Smaller preview frames decode quicker of course, but at some level, small size obscures useful detail. In the first versions, Android's preview size on the G1 was 480x320 and this was just fine for QR codes and most 1D barcodes. I'd suggest at least, say, 800x480 these days, but diminishing returns come quickly here.

Comment: Using Google Glass, I was able to build a PlanarYUVLuminanceSource and pass it a preview frame byte array of size 640x480 (the 4:3 ratio for proper glass camera preview). I didn't use a framing rectangle when building the PlanarYUVLuminanceSource and the library decodes consistently when the QR code is at a distance of ~1.5 feet away from the device.